# How to get angled corner like this in CSS, it's not round?

Tags: css

How to get angled corner like this in CSS, it's not round?

I tried with for left side (Example) but it's not giving the same effect

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect page for your question - it explains in detail (with photos too) how to get different curves using different CSS, including one like your question's pic:

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

The one that looks most like yours (imo) is:

```
#Example_C {
    height: 65px;
    width:160px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
border-bottom-left-radius:20px 60px;
```

Answer (score 0):

by looking at http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/
I would think it would be

`border-bottom-left-radius : 50px 100px;`

`border-bottom-right-radius : 50px 100px;`